# can we use user input data from one form in another form of same page

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two forms in the same page, the first form will have `email`, `name`, `password` etc.

In a second form there are `qualification`, `skills`, `institution` etc.

I will add data from the first form into one table. I want to take the ID of the  data from the first form and add `qualifications`, `skills` and `institution` in another table along with the ID from the first form.

I am doing this in php. Please give me an idea how to implement this.

Comment: you can use hidden field user id in both form

Comment: It would be helpful to post the HTML/PHP that you do have, so we may make suggestions based upon the work you've already done. I feel sometimes my suggestions are rather off base without being able to see what you've already tried. Anyhow, @DevsiOdedra's suggestion is valid, you may use hidden form ID's in this case. I can think of many suggestions that may or may not work for you, such as using Sessions, combining both forms into one, using JS to edit one form's input based on another, a lot depends on your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it with Ajax

User enters email, pass..etc, and clicks submit button after that trigger Ajax Call with form data. Store the data in your table and return Mysql Last Inserted Id. Store Last Inserted Id in your load JS Variable/HTML Hidden value.

Steps :

```
- User Enters Details and press Submit button
- Ajax call triggers with your data
- get Last Insert id from back-end(ajax response)
- store id in html hidden value or js variable
- use this details for next form
```